# Required input textbox is always invalidate on Angular 5 & KendoUI

Tags: angular, validation, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I try to make a form with KendoUI and Angular 4. I have some required field. All works fine except `<input kendoTextBox required/>` which is red even before the user write something in it.
Here is the code:

```
<form #identityForm="ngForm" class="k-form">

    <label class="k-form-field">
        <span>Profession</span>
        <!-- This required input is red even before the user try to write something -->
        <input kendoTextBox required [(ngModel)]="profession" name="profession"/>
    </label>

    <label class="k-form-field">
        <span>Country</span>
        <!-- This required input have the good behaviour -->
        <kendo-autocomplete required name="country" [(ngModel)]="country" [data]="countries">
        </kendo-autocomplete>
    </label>

</form>

<button [disabled]="!identityForm.valid">Submit</button>
```

On [KendoUI documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/inputs/textbox/), it seems to works well.

What should I need to modify to invalidate required field only when user click on submit button? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi i hope it will be useful to others.kendo textbox ng-invalid before submit.
what about this handling in css not property.demo link here.

```
.k-textbox.ng-invalid:not(.k-invalid) 
        {
            border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08) !important
        }
```

`<kendo-textbox formControlName="name" placeholder="Enter Name"  [ngClass]="{'k-invalid':submitted && form.get('name').errors?.required }"> </kendo-textbox>`

https://angular-8os2ur.stackblitz.io